# TypeError: search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_results'

Tags: python

```
 #Importar la biblioteca de Google Search y BeautifulSoup
from googlesearch import search
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Realizar una búsqueda en Google
results = search("Python", num_results=10)

# Abrir un archivo de texto en modo de escritura
with open('resultados.txt', 'w') as file:
# Iterar a través de los resultados y obtener los h1, h2 y h3
    for result in results:
        # Realizar una solicitud HTTP a la URL del resultado
        page = requests.get(result.link)
        # Analizar el contenido de la página con BeautifulSoup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        # Extraer las etiquetas h1, h2 y h3
        h1 = soup.find_all('h1')
        h2 = soup.find_all('h2')
        h3 = soup.find_all('h3')
        # Escribir los contenidos de las etiquetas h1, h2 y h3 en el archivo de texto
        file.write("h1: " + str([tag.text for tag in h1]) + "\n")
        file.write("h2: " + str([tag.text for tag in h2]) + "\n")
        file.write("h3: " + str([tag.text for tag in h3]) + "\n")
```

I get an error here "results = search("Python", num_results=10)" can anybody help me?

Create a scrapper that grab h1 h2 and h3 from top 10 websites in google

Comment: The error is the post tittle TypeError: search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_results'

Comment: Works for me, can't reproduce it. What library version do you use? Is this the whole code? Have you redefined `search` somewhere?

Comment: But i need to track the first 10 results :c

Comment: Yes , this is the whole code about lib just import google ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've installed a different library. Either use

```
pip install googlesearch-python
```

to install the one you are trying to use. Or read the [docs of the one that you are using](https://python-googlesearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Its already installed but got the same error

Comment: What is installed? `google` or `googlesearch-python`? Can you share an output of `pip freeze`?

Comment: beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
certifi==2022.9.24
chardet==4.0.0
google==3.0.0
googlesearch-python==1.1.0
idna==2.10
requests==2.25.1
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
urllib3==1.26.13

Comment: Try uninstalling `google` with `pip uninstall google`. You import the wrong `module` because both are installed

Comment: After execute "pip unsintall google" now get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googlesearch'"

Answer (score 0):

just install these modules and it works.

```
pip install google
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).